# Actionscript 3.0 click on hidden object

Tags: actionscript-3, hidden, mouseclick-event

I have a hidden DisplayObject (`myObj.visible = false;`). I've provided a listener:

```
myObj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myHandler);
```

By myHandler does never fires. It seems that `MouseEvent.CLICK` is not delivered for hidden objects...
How can I listen to `MouseEvent.CLICK` for my hidden object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to put it with alpha=0.

```
var myDisplayObject = DisplayObject(myObj);
myDisplayObject.alpha = 0
myDisplayObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler);
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I just wonder: itn't setting alpha = 0 a hack? Is it "officially recommended" way in such sutuations?

Comment: in fact, its not a Hack, cause actionscript is full oriented to assets elements, but with alpha 0 the AVM recognize this assets as full accessible, his properties are not disabled, and in case of a large number of assets ( with alpha 0) the render CPU will be affected, in this case must switch it to Render GPU.